# With Fiber's context, how do I iterate over multiple files?

Tags: go, go-fiber

When I receive a `post` request with a list of files to be uploaded to the server, I can get a specific file, if I know the name of it via

`c.FormFile("filename")`

But how would I iterate over the files in that list, without knowing the files names ahead of time? I don't see a method listed in the `context` docs that simply provides a list of files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [c.MultiPartForm()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofiber/fiber#Ctx.MultipartForm) to get a [*multipart.Form](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Form).  Iterate through the form's [File](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Form.File) field.

```
form, err := ctx.MultipartForm()
if err != nil { /* handle error */ }
for formFieldName, fileHeaders := range form.File {
    for _, fileHeader := range fileHeaders {
        // process uploaded file here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was not obvious from the documentation.